# Separar paréntesis al formatear código Dart (Flutter) en Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, vscode, dart, formato

Me encuentro estudiando Flutter, pero al formatear mi código, Visual Studio Code me organiza los paréntesis de la forma en la que se ve en la captura...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no me gusta, quisiera que se vieran así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Llevo bastante rato buscando en la configuración y no encuentro la forma de hacerlo... quisiera saber si es posible hacerlo, ya sea instalando alguna extensión o bien, configurándolo...

Comment: Usa trailings commas. No es lo que pides, pero te ayudará a mejorar la legibilidad del código

Answer (score 0):

Ok, conseguí hacer que al formatear se hiciera un salto de línea en los paréntesis, era tan simple como añadir una coma después del paréntesis que cierra al Widget...

Codigo de ejemplo

```
      ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        child: FadeInImage(
          placeholder: AssetImage('assets/images/no-image.jpg'),
          image: NetworkImage(movie.fullPosterImg),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          height: 150,
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 20,
      ),
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: size.width - 200),
            child: Text(
              movie.title,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              maxLines: 2,
            ),
          ),
```